# installing kobo with python creates path errors

Tags: python-2.7

I have python 2.7.3 installed on my system an I am trying to install Kobo module. The path where the module is located is:

`C:\Users\nelson.menezes\Desktop\new softwares\kobo-0.3.6`

.I opened the command promt and set the above mentioned path. Then as specified I run the following command to install Kobo.

```
python setup.py install
```

But it gives me the following error

```
File "c:\python27\lib\distutils\util.py", line 204, in convert_path
raise ValueError, "path '%s' cannot be absolute" % pathname
ValueError: path '/usr/bin' cannot be absolute
```

I know that it an error generated due to Path problems. But I cannot figure out how to resolve it. It would be great if anyone could help in any possible way. My rights to ask questions have been removed. So I am editing the question in order to resolve my problem. Sorry for the inconvenience but i really need to get this error resolved.

Comment: This is a very broad question and very open ended ... did you try sqa.stackexchange?

Comment: I know that it is a broad question. But right now I just wanted a few parameters if you could help.

Comment: eh? Dude, do not edit old questions. Ask new instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I opened my [JIRA](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) bug tracking tool and here is what we are actually using:

- Project
- Issue type (bug, improvement, new feature)
- Summary
- Priority (Blocker, Critical, Major, Minor, Trivial)
- Affects version/s
- Fix Version/s
- Description
- Attachment field
- Component/s (e.g "GUI", "Backend" ... it is configurable)
- Due Date
- Reporter (auto filled in username of reporter)
- Environment
- Original Estimate (how long fixing this will last, e.g 3w 5d 8h)
- Labels

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Priority
2) Browser
3) Actual result
4) Expected result
```